# Blowfish Encryption Problems

Tags: java, android, encryption

Please before you mark this as a duplicate understand that I can not find any helpful information on stackoverflow about blowfish. I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt strings with blowfish using Android Studio. My encryption seems to work. But when I try to decrypt said string it is substantially shorter and encoded with characters. I'm very new to encryption any help is greatly appreciated.

Encryption

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class Encryption {

private String algorithm = "Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private SecretKeySpec keySpec;
private Cipher cipher;


public void setupForEncryption(String keyString) throws java.security.GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] keyData = keyString.getBytes();
    keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Blowfish");
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
}

public SecretKeySpec getSecretKey() {
    return keySpec;
}

public boolean checkForKeySpec() {
    if (keySpec != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String encryptString(String inputString) throws java.security.GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keySpec.getEncoded());
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(),ivSpec);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return new String(encryptedBytes);
}
```

Decryption

```
import android.util.Base64;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Decryption {

private SecretKeySpec keySpec;
private String algorithm = "Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private Cipher cipher;

public void setupForDecryption(String key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] keyData = key.getBytes();
    keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "Blowfish");
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
}

public boolean checkForKeySpec() {
    if(keySpec !=  null){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public SecretKeySpec getSecretKey() {
    return keySpec;
}

public String decryptString(String inputString) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keySpec.getEncoded());
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(),ivSpec);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = Base64.decode(inputString,0);
    String decrypted = new String(decryptedBytes);
    return decrypted;
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a more than decade old encryption algorithm like Blowfish ?

Comment: Blowfish, neat name, used it a decade ago, old algorithm. The current standard is AES (Advanced Encryption Algorithm), the name says it all.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this during encryption:

```
return new String(encryptedBytes);
```

where `encryptedBytes` can consist of any byte value. By forcing those bytes to be converted to a String, you're essentially dropping those bytes that are not printable in the default encoding.

Furthermore, during decryption, you forgot to decrypt (`cipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes("UTF-8"))`). I only see `Base64.decode`, which is an encoding and not encryption.

If you want to send strings, then you need to encode the byte array into a printable string with encodings such as Base64 or Hex.

---

Always use a specific encoding when converting from bytes to string `bytes.getBytes("UTF-8")` and back `new String(str, "UTF-8")`. Otherwise, you could run into incompatibilities between devices when the default charset changes.

Always use a random IV with CBC mode. It provides semantic security. The IV doesn't have to be secret, so you can simply send it along with the ciphertext and use it during decryption. It's common to simply prefix it to the ciphertext.